# Cannot Insert Data into Datatable after Clear Function

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple Visual Basic (.net) form application that works as a menu ordering system.

On the main screen you select the image and the insert query adds the item to the slip (database).

```
Private Sub btnChicken_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChicken.Click
    Table1TableAdapter.Insert("Chicken Burger", 1, "R29.00")
```

Once they click Print Slip then the Clear query goes through and deletes all the rows:

```
OrderDataSet.Tables("Table1").Rows.Clear()
```

the issue is once it clears then the previous form opens again where a new customer can start their order but when they click the food image. The Insert query no longer adds it to the datatable.

Comment: What's the point of the `DataTable` at all when you're inserting directly to the database?  I think you need to spend a bit more time learning how typed `DataSets` and their table adapters work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the datatable will be used later for Employee data and order history. We are just testing it for now.

Comment: Then it seems that you have added irrelevant information to your question, which suggests that you don't really understand the issue well enough.  If that `Insert` method is executed then either a record will be inserted or an exception will be thrown.  If no record is inserted then either that line isn't being executed or it's throwing an exception.  Have you actually put a breakpoint on it to see if it's executed?  Have you tested the value it returns?

Comment: I have resolved the issue.I was not ending the form when the insert query had finished and therefor it would not re initiate the Insert Query. Thank you for the assistance everyone.